# How to convert PPTX to XML using vba or applescript?

Tags: xml, vba, applescript, powerpoint

I need to export my active presentation as XMl file. Please help me to achive.
Is it possible to do using VBA or Applescript from MAC

There is an option in powerpoint to export pptx as xml file
File -> Save as -> XML file
I need to achieve this without user interaction using vba or applescript.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Powerpoint you do not need VBA. Simply use the save as dialogue and save your pptx as powerpoint xml presentation.

[image: Dialog]

**[Link](http://%20https://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/powerpoint-to-xml/)**

Comment: Did you try this?